# PKIX path building failed. Self-signed SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, pkix

I created server and client **keystore.jks** and **truststore.jks** pairs.
**server-truststore.jks** contains **client-public.cer**, **client-truststore.jks** contains **server-public.cer**.
SSL certificates have no CAs, are self-signed ones. If I play the communication locally it works. But after deploying my server I get the exception:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I've tried to put my server/client certificates into carcerts of java security, it didn't help.

The communication only works if I call my WS from SOAP UI. (For SOAP UI I don't need to use **truststore.jks**)

I checked it out with a famous SSLPoke.class

```
$ java SSLPoke HOST 443
Successfully connected

$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks SSLPoke HOST 443
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

What could solve it?

Comment: Did you set the identity store properly for the server? If that's not the case, try enabling SSL debugging and check what's going wrong

Comment: Or a little more focussed: use `keytool -printcert -sslserver host:443` to display (without validating) the cert received from the server (or alternatively `openssl s_client` and `openssl x509 -text -noout`) and `keytool -list [-v] -keystore truststore.jks` to see exactlly what your truststore contains, and check they match.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've found. The problem was the port. My local port is 433, but the remote was 8443.